# Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called” in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, proguard

Seen at least 2 similar questions, but both considering eclipse non gradle builds.

I'm trying to assemble release with gradle using:

```
./gradlew myapp:assembleRelease --stacktrace
```

Besides newest Google proguard example my proguard.txt contains:

```
# ButterKnife
-keep class *$$ViewInjector{}
-dontwarn butterknife.Views$InjectViewProcessor
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**

#JodaTime
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**

#Apache
-dontnote org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

This seemed to remove all the warnings but now struggling with mysterious

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called
```

...and I have no clue what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct proguard config for those 3 libraries:

```
# ButterKnife
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}

#JodaTime
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**

#Apache
-keep public class org.apache.commons.io.**
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-dontnote org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

Not sure if it was a gradle update, but that doesn't happen anymore

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and never discovered the root of the issue. I did find that if you add a rule to skip optimization in your proguard file it stops the build error from happening.

```
-dontoptimize
```

Answer (score 1):

`-dontoptimize` specifies not to optimize the input class files, I am
   not sure if it is a good idea to disable optimization, better will be
   to enable or disable individual optimizations.

In your case you can use `-optimizations` `optimization_filter`

```
-optimizations !class/merging/vertical*,!class/merging/horizontal*
```

Proguard will perform all optimizations, except the ones that merges classes vertically and merges classes horizontally.

[more info here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/optimizations.html)